# can't change background image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the `background` `image` when clicking `play` button, the background image is supposed to change to `pause`, vice versa. Now I can play and pause the music, but I can not change images. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?
here is my code:

```
function initAudioPlayer() {
    audio_0 = new Audio();
    audio_0.src = "audio/footprint.mp3";

    //set object reference
    playbtn0 = document.getElementById("audio-play-images-0");
    forwardbtn0 = document.getElementById("audio-next-images-0");
    backbtn0 = document.getElementById("audio-prev-images-0");

    //add event handling
    playbtn0.addEventListener("click", playPause);
    forwardbtn0.addEventListener("click", playForward);
    backbtn0.addEventListener("click", playBack);
}

function playPause() {
    if (audio_0.paused) {
        audio_0.play();
        playbtn0.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/pause-on.png)';
    } else {
        audio_0.pause();
        playbtn0.style.backgroundImage = "url('../img/play-on.png')";
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="audio-controls">
     <div id="audio-prev-images-0"></div>
     <div id="audio-play-images-0"></div>
     <div id="audio-next-images-0"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: check the browser console for errors..

Comment: at what point are you creating the `playbtn0` variable?

Comment: the first line in js file, I create playbtn0 as a global variable.

Comment: See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/j46hst0j/2/).. click the green div..as you can see, the fiddle is working fine..

Comment: @RachelGallen I added playbtn0.style.backgroundSize = "40px 40px", but it is still not working

Comment: @JenniferHe did you try it with contain?

Comment: @JenniferHe are you setting a background image in the css? if so it should be .css and not .style and you should add !important

Comment: @RachelGallen Thank you very much for your help. I am new to javascript , Could you elaborate it?

Comment: do you have a css stylesheet that is linking in to your html

Comment: @RachelGallen yes, I have, the code is:<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

Comment: check it and see if there is a background image set in for the playbtn0 and pausebtn0

Comment: you can open it if you open your page and view source and then click on the style.css link

Comment: did you find it? just search for playbtn using Ctrl+ F when you have the css open

Comment: @RachelGallen trying it:)

Comment: @JenniferHe anyway if there is a background-image attribute in the css, then it needs to be overwritten, so you need to specify .css because you are using css and not inline style, and your  playbtn0.css.backgroundImage = url(yourpath/img) must have !important after it to overwrite what is already in the css

Comment: @RachelGallen I got this msg" net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" but my images are in the folder

Comment: when did you get the error? when you looked for the images or the css?

Comment: @RachelGallen When I debug the webpage, the error is showed in html console. I also add "playbtn0.style.backgroundColor="red" "", this code is working. I think you r right, I need to change the background image size also. but I add playbtn0.style.backgroundSize = "contain" which is not working

Comment: give the image the full file path in the url and make sure it is correct and it should work. Go to the image and see where it is, it may be in an image folder.

Comment: @JenniferHe please if you find my help useful pls hover beside my answer and check the checkmark beside it. it will turn green. :) thanks

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks for your help. I will do that:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there is a background-image attribute in the css, then it needs to be overwritten, so your `playbtn0.css.backgroundImage = url(yourpath/img)` will overwrite what is already in the css.

Then you should see a difference. You should also make sure the css has a background-size of `contain` so that it fits.

Edit: this was tagged as jquery initially - use .style

Comment: It does not require `!important`, javascript applies in-line styles that allways override styles contained in .css

Comment: I'm not sure where you got .css from either? It should definitely be .style. Maybe you're thinking of the .css function found in jQuery? Either way, there's no such property in the native DOM elements.

Comment: @OskarEriksson well i've used it so it must exist

Comment: Nope. Try opening the console and run console.dir(document.getElementById("mainbar")) on this page and you'll see that there's no such property anywhere in the prototype chain. There is , however, a style property.

Comment: @RachelGallen, you must be thinking of the [`css()` jQuery function/method](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2). As Oskar points out, there is no such property on HTML elements. [`.style` would work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) tho.

Comment: @Qtax i edited my answer to highlight this. this question was tagged jquery until i untagged it

Comment: @RachelGallen, you cannot use the `.css()` jQuery function like in your answer. That is the example in your answer is wrong. One way to use it would be: `$(domNodeOrSelector).css("background-image", "url(foo/bar)");`

Comment: @OskarEriksson It wasn't clear since you made the edit and not her. So if you remove the first line, you should remove the Edit part as well since it makes no sense anymore...

Comment: @ForceMagic agreed. I did that but that edit was rejected, so I don't know what's what anymore. :)

Comment: @OskarEriksson Oh lol, that's another problem when reviewing, we cannot see historic review, I'll do it then. I guess if it would have been in the same suggestion it might have passed!

Comment: Can you validate if my edit is Ok? I'm not sure @OskarEriksson and I had the same idea than you about it.

Comment: Oh well, I'll leave it be, your Edit makes not sense to me, You removed the jquery tag from the OP`s question and then you edit your reply to include that it was originally tagged as such...